# rails_admin_import: Error during import:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-admin

In my models I have an `AssessmentItem` which `has_many :items_levels`. When I try to import an `ItemLevel` I get the error

> Error during import: AssessmentItem(#70286054976500) expected, got
>   AssessmentItem(#70286114743280)
>   (/Users/stoebelj/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:218:inraise_on_type_mismatch!')

As far as I know, the parent record exists and I am referencing it with the correct mapping key.

Can someone give me an idea of what this error means and what might be the culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I's too having these problems.

Since, in development environment, each time you make changes to class and save it in any editor, the class is registered as a new class and hence the mismatch of class' object instances.

1. Stop rails server
2. Run it again
3. Reload your page
4. Now, try uploading again

Repeat each time you make any changes to your code.